# Shortest path in an edge-weighted DAG with multiple source vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given an algorithm A that computes the longest path from a source vertex s in a DAG G with non-negative edge weights. What is the minimum number of times required to run the algorithm A to find the longest path in a DAG G?

One way is to figure out the multiple source vertices, this can be achieved in O(|Edges|). And then run Algorithm A with each of these vertices as a source vertex. This will require running algorithm A NumberOfSourceVertices times.

Can we do better ?

Comment: We can find the multiple source vertices in O(|Edges|). Let's assume the graph is same.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can do better.  Add a new node `z` to `G`.  For every identified source vertex `s`, add an edge `(z, s, 0)` (zero edge weight) to G.

Run `A` *once* on the modified `G`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was talking about.

Comment: As worded, you can do even better.  Write your own algorithm `B` for longest path -- say, and implementation of Dijkstra's, fully optimized, that you find with a 30-minute search.  Build the augmented graph.  Run `B` on it.  You have no found the longest path without running `A` at all.  :-)